# align fields of a php variable

Tags: php, html, css

I have a php to echo three variable fields :

```html
<li>
     <mark>  <?php  while( $toprow2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3) ) {
     echo   $toprow2['overallRank']     ."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$toprow2['EmployeeName']     ."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded']."<br/>";}  ?>
     </mark>
</li>
```

Among these three variables of the list,I want to align the first field "overallRank " to left ,"EmployeeName " to centre and "Total_points_Rewarded" to extreme right.

Below is the code I tried  for the first field:

```html
<li>
    <mark>  <?php  while( $toprow2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3) ) {
                          echo  "<div style = "text-align=left" ."$toprow2['overallRank'] "</div>"."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$toprow2['EmployeeName'] ."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded']."<br/>";}  ?>
    </mark>
</li>
```

**when I use three divs :**

```
echo  "<div style ='text-align:left'>" . $toprow2['overallRank'] . "</div><div style ='text-align:left'>" . $toprow2['EmployeeName'] . "</div><div style ='text-align:right'>" . $toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</div>";
```

I am not able to align them :Current scenario :

[image]

the first block is the rank,then name and last points -  the three fields that I am trying to echo here.

Comment: Why don't you use three divs instead of one? Then you can easily align them...

Comment: @d.coder I tried using.But i am not able to align.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your content elements with `<div>` and use flexbox to align your items, e.g. like this:

```css
li mark {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
li mark div {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <mark>
    <div>some content</div>
    <div>some content</div>
    <div>some content</div>
  </mark>
</li>
```

Your PHP code would than probably look like this:

```
<li>
    <mark>
        <?php  while( $toprow2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3) ) {
            echo  "<div>" . $toprow2['overallRank'] . "</div><div>" . $toprow2['EmployeeName'] . "</div><div>" . $toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</div>";
        } ?>
    </mark>
</li>
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) for more information or [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a nice guide.

Comment: thanks for the input.I am not able to align the three divs  in a single row.

Comment: i have modified the question above and presented the current scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You could still use list you would want to add the style to your style sheet but you will get the idea

Add new classes to style sheet

```
/* CSS layout */
.rstlist {
}        
.ovrank {
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;
width:33%;text-align:center
}
.emname {
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;
width:33%;text-align:center
}
.tpr {
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;
width:33%;text-align:center
}
```

Then here is the edited script

```
<?php  while( $toprow2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3) ) {
echo '<ul class="rstlist">' . PHP_EOL .
        '<li class="ovrank">' . $toprow2['overallRank'] . '</li>' . PHP_EOL .
        '<li class="emname">' . $toprow2['EmployeeName'] . '</li>' . PHP_EOL .
        '<li class="tpr">' . $toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded'] .'</li>' . PHP_EOL .
'<ul>';
}
?>
```

Now you can view in different browsers and adjust the style of each element to get your desired look based on you actual output...

Comment: Thanks for the input.But i am not able to align,if I use your solution. @Chop62

Comment: @ Jane Augustine You should be able to adjust the css to align everything based on your output I would create a class for each line and adjust the display for what you want I have no way of knowing what the results of your query will look like you could create classes for each element and adjust the css for each to get the desired look I added a new example to answer.